How do I create an htaccess file?
I want to create a .htaccess file but whenever I do it the code I insert in it doesn't work
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]


I"m using visual studio code and I want to remove the .html thing from the url. So, I need to know how to connect a .htaccess file to a html file and how to create a .htaccess file in vsc.
I haven't tried doing anything because I've been searching for solutions but I couldn't find anything. Everything I find online is about the code I can use in a .htaccess file, not how to create it nor how to connect it.
For some reason I tried doing this:
<head>
<link rel="htaccess" href="index.htaccess">
</head>

But it didn't work.

A .htaccess file (note the leading dot in the filename) is just a standard text file. However, you need to be using the Apache webserver and the webserver needs to be configured to allow .htaccess files to be processed. "For some reason I tried doing this" - yeah, that doesn't make sense. A .htaccess file is a server configuration file. It has nothing to do with your HTML (and CSS, JS) files directly.

Note that to remove the ".html thing" from the URL - you do this first in your internal links. .htaccess should not be used to "remove" it. .htaccess allows your URLs (without .html) to "work" by internally rewriting the request back to include .html, so the underlying files can be found. eg. You link to /myhomepage in your HTML and .htaccess internally rewrites this request to /myhomepage.html (the name of the underlying file). The end user does not see the .html extension anywhere since it does not appear in your HTML source or in the browser address bar.

Thanks!
But I don't know how to use that "Apache webserver" and configure it. Could you please elaborate?

You need a http server to publish stuff "on the web". There are different such server components. The most typical one is the apache http server. It is a server component you can operate on any system. It publishes files on that system such that they can be retrieved by a requesting web browser on a different system.

Installing an apache http server is easy. On a Linux system (the typical base for a server system in the internet) you simply check the apache http server in the software management, that is all, the system does thje rest. On MS-Windows and MacOS you have to download the software first. Make sure to pick the correct one, there are many sites offering altered versions that contain malware. Start at apache.org . Additionally you need to open the listening ports in your firewall. Otherwise incoming requests will get blocked.
